# How to get author from Wikimedia BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

Hi I have currently been facing issues with getting the author from a wikimedia photo.
bs4 find is always returning None and I'm getting pretty stuck. I was wondering if someone code show me some code that may work.

> Example wikimedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden_Retriever_Carlos_(10581910556).jpg

[image: Wikimedia summary]

> My aim is to get the authors name and its corresponding link

Current code

```
html_content = requests.get(url).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

#This return None though
table = soup.find("table", {'class': "fileinfotpl-type-information toccolours vevent mw-content-ltr"})
```

Comment: Hi, I think it would help a lot if you share your relevant code and probably the related html source.

Comment: Hi @NiklasMertsch  I have just edited it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden_Retriever_Carlos_(10581910556).jpg'    
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Author")').find_next('td').get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Dirk Vorderstraße
```

Comment: Elegant Code +1. You can scrape a lot with just css selectors

Comment: Hi I have tried this with other wikimedia urls and they don't seem to work. please try https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Struthio_camelus_-_Etosha_2014_%283%29.jpg

Comment: @GILO I tried it and it prints `Yathin S Krishnappa`. See my edit.

Comment: @AndrejKesely i get this error "Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
"

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden_Retriever_Carlos_(10581910556).jpg")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

author_td = soup.find("table", class_="fileinfotpl-type-information toccolours vevent mw-content-ltr").find("tbody").find_all("tr")[-1]

print(author_td.find_all("td")[-1].get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Dirk Vorderstraße
```